# Getting rid of if directive in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a Django app which has nginx as a reverse proxy with gunicorn as an application web server (upstream).

In the `location /` block of my nginx virtual host file, I refer to a unix socket in the web application server like so:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://application_server;
    break;
}
```

Idea being that don't need to get gunicorn to serve static assets, nginx ought to take care of them.

I have two related questions:
1) Performance wise, having that kind of `if else` type check on nginx can be costly. Have you seen that in your experience? My web app is a high traffic social forum and lots of static assets require serving. Thoughts, do's and dont's (if any)? Need more info?

2) It's well documented that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in an nginx context. How do I change the `if` directive with a `try_files` one? I gave it a shot myself; it looked straight-forward. But crashed and burnt every time. Here's what I try:

- Replace the entire `if` directive by `try_files $uri @application_server;`
- Include a `location @application_server` block below `location /`; this contains `proxy_pass http://application server`.
- There's an `upstream application_server` block at the top of the config file (outside `server`), this contains a reference to the unix socket and `fail_timout=0;`.

Should have worked, no? Ask me for more info if you need it.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is the result you are getting? What do the logs say? Did you try nginx debug log?

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie: Here's what comes up in the application server: `Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myapp/myapp.sock`. For nginx logs, I'll revert to the erroneous set up and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you posted is returned by Django, because it cannot figure out the hostname part of the URL.

When you proxy from a web server, you have to pass through this header explicitly.

The critical line you are missing is:

```
location @application_server {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    ...
```

See also the [sample nginx configuration](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html) in the gunicorn documentation.